# Fading between images in a carousel

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I've been trying to understand why my carousel won't fade between transitions.  It cycles as expected, but don't seem to apply the transition effect to make one panel fade in to the next.

Here's what I have so far:

```
/* Javascript */
function cycle() {
    var active = $('.carousel .item.active');
    var panels = $('.carousel .item');
    var pos = panels.index(active);
    var next = panels.eq((pos >= 5) ? 0 : ++pos);

    next.addClass('active');
    active.removeClass('active');
}

var interval = setInterval(cycle, 2000);

/* CSS */
.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel .item {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
.carousel .item.active {
    opacity: 1;
}

/* HTML */
<div id="id_landing_carousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item" data-nav-button="nav-home">
            <img src="/media/carousel/home.png">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4><p>Welcome</p></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-nav-button="nav-residential">
            <img src="/media/carousel/residential.jpg">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4><p>Residential</p></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-nav-button="nav-commercial">
            <img src="/media/carousel/commercial.jpg">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4><p>Commercial</p></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-nav-button="nav-service">
            <img src="/media/carousel/service.jpg">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4><p>Service</p></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item active" data-nav-button="nav-blog">
            <img src="/media/carousel/blog.jpg">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4><p>Blog</p></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-nav-button="nav-contact">
            <img src="/media/carousel/contact.jpg">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4><p>Contact us</p></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If anyone has any insight in to what I"m doing wrong, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: It would help if you provided a jsfiddle.

Comment: I put it into a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ESTpu/), and slowed down the transition speed to get a better feel for how it was working. I'm not quite sure what the problem is, near as I can tell it's fading in and out just fine in chrome 22. What browser are you testing this in?

Comment: Do you want the images to overlap?

Comment: Well now I'm really stumped.  It works there in my browser as well (Chrome 22 on OSX).  No idea why this isn't working on my live site.

Answer (score 0):

Damn.  Nevermind.  Solved it myself.  Another style was setting the carousel's div element to display: none when it wasn't `active`.